# Holder condition using second difference

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

I want to find a simple proof for, for $0<\alpha<1$, if $f\in C_c^0(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfies $|f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)|\le C|x|^\alpha$, then $f\in C^\alpha(\mathbb R^n)$.

I saw in Zygmund's [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077472961) had this statement (lemma 4), also in Triebel's Theory of Function Spaces II. But Triebel doesn't give a direct proof as well.

Comment: Due to $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so it is a bounded function. Thus there always exists a constant M such that $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq M|x|^{\alpha},\ \ \forall |x|\gg1$. Then the second difference provides us the behaviour near the origin. Hence these two parts provide the $C^{\alpha}$ of f at the origin. I think the proof wouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: @Zixiao_Liu I doubt that, because this is not true for $\alpha=1$. And the compact support is actually useless here because I don't want potentially counterexample shows up

Comment: I don't think there is a very simple proof, because the first difference is not bounded by the second difference (take a linear function). You are basically asking a proof of Marchaud inequality for this special case. If you want, I can write a "simplish" proof tailored to the case.